# Format SOAP request envelope [node js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap

I am trying to format a SOAP request envelope using node js, which should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
  <env:Body>
    <env:getStaffRecords env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
      <params xsi:type="ns1:Map">
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">limit</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">3</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">page</key>
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
        </item>
      </params>
    </env:getStaffRecords>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I referred to: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Strong-soap.html#xml-attributes

However, I couldn't get the expected output. Below is my demo code and output I got.

```
"use strict";

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var WSDL = soap.wsdl;
var url = "https://testrequest.ch/api/soap/whoswho/wsdl";

// var args = null;
// var args = {limit: '10', page: '1'};

var args = {
    params: {       
        $attributes: {
            $xsiType: "ns1:Map",          
        },
        item: [{
            key: {
                $attributes: {
                    $xsiType: "xsd:string",             
                },
                $value: "limit"         
            },
            value: {
                $attributes: {
                    $xsiType: "xsd:string",             
                },
                $value: "3"
            }               
        }, {
            key: {
                $attributes: {
                    $xsiType: "xsd:string",             
                },
                $value: "page"          
            },
            value: {
                $attributes: {
                    $xsiType: "xsd:string",             
                },
                $value: "1"
            }               
        }]
    }};

var wsdlOptions = {
};

soap.createClient(url, wsdlOptions, function(err, client){  
    client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity("api_noob", "randompassword"));   
    client.getStaffRecords(args, function(err, result, envelope){
         //console.log(envelope);
        //console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log('last request: ', client.lastRequest);
    })  
});
```

Which generates request envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:getStaffRecords xmlns:ns1="https://testrequest.ch/api/whoswho/">
      <params xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2=""
 xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
          <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="
" xsi:type="xsd:string">limit</key>
          <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd
="" xsi:type="xsd:string">3</value>
        </item>
        <item>
          <key xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="
" xsi:type="xsd:string">page</key>
          <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd
="" xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
        </item>
      </params>
    </ns1:getStaffRecords>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```